# Liquid Simulation with small Emitter in large Domain?

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

My problem is that my emitter only emits liquid when the emitter is big or the domain small enough. But I need a very small emitter that is supposed to squirt water within a large domain. Is that somehow possible? That can't be such a problem, or? It's supposed to be just a small water cable within a large room, but the water can splash a long way, so I need a correspondingly large domain. I have Blender 3.1.
Thanks!

Tim

Comment: yes it is if you make your resolution really high. But this will cause the simulation to be VERY slow.

Comment: Have you tweaked the Resolution Divisions value, and also, under Liquid, the Particle Raidus and the Sampling values?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I´ve now tried to set up the resolution divisions to 800 and played with the particle radius and the sampling value but no liquid :(

Comment: I have now made the domain significantly smaller and the emitter a bit larger and now at least something is displayed. But the particles are extremely large and the resolution is extremely poor despite the high resolution division (400), which takes an extremely long time to bake even with an i9 12900k, even for only 10 frames.

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file (only the domain and inflow objects): https://pasteall.org/blend/